# Flutter: Is there a way to hide the Emojis, GIFs, ... -Tabs in the keyboard?

Tags: flutter, emoji, textinput

We want to hide the  Emojis, GIFs, ... -Tabs in the keyboard. The only thing working we found is using the Keyboard Type TextInputType.visiblePassword. The problem is that we want to use the correct TextInputType for the current situation and TextInputType.visiblePassword disables autoSuggestions.

Answer (score 0):

How about :

```
keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
```

I’ve tested on iOS & it does show autoSuggestions