# Flutter - Disable TextField image insert options

Tags: flutter

I searched everywhere and couln't find any solution...

How to disable the `image insert`/`gif`/`translation` options in the `TextField`/`TextFormField` widgets?

[image]

Comment: I fear that your settings could be overwritten by the OS, even if you find a way to hide the buttons on the default keyboard. I mean, any device can have multiple keyboard apps installed, at least on Android, and the Os would load the one selected by the user. Probably you could look for a keyboard package to use.

Answer (score 0):

make the enableInteractiveSelection property to false of the TextField

```
enableInteractiveSelection:false,
```

you can read the details in the official documentation [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField/enableInteractiveSelection.html)

Comment: Its not this option, this option disable text selection and related stufs...

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `KeyboardType` to accept only text in the `TextField`:

```
TextFormField(
  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
  // or keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
  ...
)
```

Comment: I'm already using `keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline`, tried with `keyboardType: TextInputType.text` and got the same result...

Comment: Ohh, I really can't say if this is some bug in flutter, since the image button in the keyboard is usually associated with the TextInputType.multiline keyboard type

Answer (score 0):

You can use the bellow property for `TextField` and `TextFormField`

```
enableSuggestions: false,
```

to stop the keyboard suggesion.

Comment: I want to keep suggestions, I want to remove the gif/sticker options

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this and see if this workaround helps in your usecase.

[hide gif/sticker in keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68499882/flutter-is-there-a-way-to-hide-the-emojis-gifs-tabs-in-the-keyboard)

This is usually normal keyboard behaviour to have those options not that it would work even if users tapped on it.

If you wish, you can code a custom keyboard without distractions by following [add custom keyboard](https://medium.com/flutter-community/custom-in-app-keyboard-in-flutter-b925d56c8465)

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the option to insert images into a TextField in Flutter by creating a custom

> TextEditingController

and overwriting the

> buildView

method to return a plain TextField.

create this

```
class NoImageTextEditingController extends TextEditingController {
  @override
  TextSpan buildTextSpan({TextStyle style, bool withComposing}) {
    return super.buildTextSpan(style: style, withComposing: false);
  }
}
```

and use it like this

```
TextField(
  controller: NoImageTextEditingController(),
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    hintText: "Enter your text here",
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

***Your gif and all suggestion is coming from the keyboard app there is some way to disable it, like if we apply password container textformfiled then it is possible like below :***

**Another way is you have to make custom keyboard for it**

```
           TextFormField(
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.visiblePassword, // add this line
                      controller: textEditingController,
                      cursorColor: AppTheme.secondaryColor,
```

> Other solution is please add this property

```
  keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline
  enableSuggestions: false,
  autocorrect: false,
```

[image]

Comment: I need it to be multiline

Comment: you can apply multiline text property into a style widget

Comment: @CaioKawasaki you can apply multiline text property into a style widget

Comment: maxLines: 5, like this

Comment: I'm doing it already and don't get a new line

Comment: i have another solun please check my answer @CaioKawasaki

Comment: @CaioKawasaki Have you check my other solution?

Comment: Yeap, none of them works, and is desired to have sugestions enabled

Comment: Its work on my device and emulator@CaioKawasaki don't know which device are you using

Comment: if you enable suggestion then gif and all other thing is visible , i think best approch to solve this please set disable suggestion and autocorrect